How to transfer Azure DevOps License from one organization to another?
I have 2 organizations under the same Active Directory. The first organization has 6 users with Basic access (not stakeholder). However, when creating a new organization, I'm only able to assign Basic access to 5 users for free. How do I transfer the license for that 6th user, so that they are able to have Basic Access in the organization as well?
Thanks in advance!
I tried removing the access completely from the old organization and then reassigning access in the new organization but I'm getting a "Failed" error.

it is not possible to transfer Azure DevOps licenses from one organization to another. Each organization has its own set of licenses and access levels, and they cannot be shared or transferred between organizations. If you have already assigned Basic access to five users in your new organization, you will need to set up billing in Azure to add additional users with Basic access. Once billing is set up, you can pay for the additional user who needs Basic access

If neither of your organizations has setup billing, you may check how many users in each organization are already on the Basic access level. If you already have 5 Basic users in one organization, you will need to change some of the existing Basic users to the unlimited free Stakeholder access level; and when you have at least 1 unassigned free basic license, you can assign the 6th user with the free Basic license.

Or you can setup billing to buy additional Basic license assignments.
In case your organizations have setup billing already. Please verify if both of your organizations have billing setups connected to the same Azure Subscription. Note that the issue is unrelated to whether the organizations are under the same Azure Active Directory (AAD).
If the billings for both organizations are linked to the same Azure Subscription and Multi-organization billing is enabled, then:

Users are billed at the Azure subscription level and the same user in multiple organizations is billed only once. Each Azure billing subscription, NOT each organization, receives 5 free users.


This setting helps avoid duplicate license charges for the same user across different organizations by maintaining the same access level. However, this might not perfectly align with the specific requirement for more free Basic licenses. Please review this this document on Billing FAQs - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn to help confirm if it can provide more free Basic licenses for your organizations by turning off the Multi-organization billing.

Q: Does multi-organization billing make sense for all customers?
A: No. For example, with the default assignment-based billing, each organization gets five free Basic users. When you change to multi-organization billing the Azure subscription gets five free Basic users, to be shared amongst all the organizations linked to it. When most users access only one organization, then five free users are most cost effective. If many users access multiple organizations, then multi-organization billing might be the best option.

